# fragments behaviour like in Gmail app

Tags: android, fragment

I want to create screen behaviours similar to Gmail app.
Looking for practical hints how to code it.

That is:
1/ on tablets
A/ when device is in landscape orientation then show fragment A i B

```
| A | B |
```

B/ in portrait orientation show only one fragment

```
|   |
| X |
|   |
```

were X = last used fragment in horizontal orientation or if 'last used == null' then A

2/ on phones
A/ for landscape

```
|   A   |
```

B/ for portrait

```
|   |
| A |
|   |
```

Screen will be integrated with NavigationDrawer.
Tnx!

Answer (score 0):

Create different layouts. You can read more [on Google](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html#Fragments) or try to use tutorial like this [Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html)